# Website inside firefox addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Can we embed a website inside a firefox addon. I am currently building an addon with multiple functions and though addon is appropriate for few functions, website is better for rest of the functions.

If I intend to create an addon and also have website embeded inside it for some of the operations, is it possible. How do we do it?

Comment: Ummm, what about iframes?

Comment: can you give some examples? what "operations" will the website do? if your website provides an API you could just hit it to do some operations, no need to embed it on the addon.

Comment: Please try to clarify your questions. Consider adding some examples of what you are going to build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have web-content in a Firefox addon, but be very careful or else the web page (or anything that intercepts the web page) will have access to everything Firefox itself could do!

If you use an XUL iframe (or any iframe element or runnable data inserted from untrusted content in Chrome:// context), please read this article carefully:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Displaying_web_content_in_an_extension_without_security_issues

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to use `iframes` for this one.

Check:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

and

http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/aaiframe.htm

Answer (score 0):

see my addon here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpicompiler/
see about:addons-memory addon here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/about-addons-memory/

very simple addons, they contain a webpage. and in the manifest file we have set contentaccesible=true

in my addon if you type about:xpiler you get to that pgae
in the other addon if you type in the url bar about:addons-memory you get to his page.

if you need help i can write a demo for you in 10 minutes

Comment: also if you want to create a sidebar with an iframe see this demo addon here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8728393